# Issue with ICommandHandler<ICommand<TEntity>> registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

I have such command interfaces:

```
public interface ICommand { }

public interface ICommand<in TEntity> : ICommand { }

public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand : class, ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

One of my generic commands looks like:

```
    public class ChangeCommand<TEntity> : ICommand<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    public TEntity entityToChange { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm using SimpleInjector of latest version. My Business config looks like:

```
public class BusinessLayerBootstrapper
{
    public static void Bootstrap(Container container)
    {
        if(container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("BusinessLayerBootstrapper container");
        }

        container.RegisterSingleton<IValidator>(new DataAnnotationsValidator(container));

        var typesToRegister = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(),
            new TypesToRegisterOptions
            {
                IncludeGenericTypeDefinitions = true,
                IncludeDecorators = false,
                IncludeComposites = false
            });
        container.RegisterCollection(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typesToRegister);

        container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(PostCommitCommandHandlerDecorator<>));

        container.Register<IPostCommitRegistrator>(() => container.GetInstance<PostCommitRegistrator>(), Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<>));
        container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(ValidationCommandHandlerDecorator<>));
        container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(AuthorizationCommandHandlerDecorator<>));

        container.Register(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), typeof(AuthorizationQueryHandlerDecorator<,>));
    }
}
```

And ASP.NET MVC config:

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Bootstrap()
    {
        Container container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

        Business.BusinessLayerBootstrapper.Bootstrap(container);

        container.Register<IPrincipal>(() => HttpContext.Current.User ?? Thread.CurrentPrincipal);

        container.RegisterSingleton<ILogger>(new FileLogger());

        container.Register<IUnitOfWork>(() => new UnitOfWork(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PriceMonitorMSSQLConnection"].ConnectionString), Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        container.Verify(VerificationOption.VerifyAndDiagnose);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

In controller I have such code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>>                                                      CreateProduct;
    ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>>                                                      ChangeProduct;
    ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>>                                                      DeleteProduct;
    ICommandHandler<ChangeProductWpriceCommand>                                             ChangeProductWprice;
    IQueryHandler<ProdStoreHierByUserQuery, IEnumerable<ProductStoreHierarchy>>             PSTree;
    IQueryHandler<ProdStoreStatByProdIdUserPeriodQuery, IEnumerable<ProductStoreStatistic>> Statistic;

    public HomeController(ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>> CreateProduct,
                          ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>> ChangeProduct,
                          ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>> DeleteProduct,
                          ICommandHandler<ChangeProductWpriceCommand> ChangeProductWprice,
                          IQueryHandler<ProdStoreHierByUserQuery, IEnumerable<ProductStoreHierarchy>> PSTree,
                          IQueryHandler<ProdStoreStatByProdIdUserPeriodQuery, IEnumerable<ProductStoreStatistic>> Statistic)
    {
        this.CreateProduct       =  CreateProduct;
        this.ChangeProduct       =  ChangeProduct;
        this.DeleteProduct       =  DeleteProduct;
        this.ChangeProductWprice =  ChangeProductWprice;
        this.PSTree              =  PSTree;
        this.Statistic           =  Statistic;
    }

    // some actions...

}
```

As a result `container.Verify` method throws an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in SimpleInjector.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type HomeController failed. The constructor of type HomeController contains the parameter with name 'CreateProduct' and type ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>> that is not registered. Please ensure `ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>>` is registered, or change the constructor of HomeController. There is, however, a registration for `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>>>`; Did you mean to depend on `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>>>`?

Same exception is thrown if I don't use `RegisterCollection` method. Could you please provide me a suggestion how to solve that problem?

**UPDATED**

According to the Steven comments I edit my question with given suggestions. My registration now is:

```
//container.RegisterCollection(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typesToRegister);
// is replaced with
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typesToRegister);
// ...
```

`Register` throws an exception:

> The supplied list of types contains one or multiple open generic types, but this method is unable to handle open generic types because it can only map closed generic service types to a single implementation. Try using RegisterCollection instead. Invalid types: ChangeCommandHandler<TEntity>, CreateCommandHandler<TEntity> and DeleteCommandHandler<TEntity>.
>   Parameter name: implementationTypes

If I leave previous code with first variant but will change my controller to this:

```
    ICommandHandler<CreateCommand<Product>> CreateProduct;
    ICommandHandler<ChangeCommand<Product>> ChangeProduct;
    ICommandHandler<DeleteCommand<Product>> DeleteProduct;
    ICommandHandler<ChangeProductWpriceCommand>                                             ChangeProductWprice;
    IQueryHandler<ProdStoreHierByUserQuery, IEnumerable<ProductStoreHierarchy>>             PSTree;
    IQueryHandler<ProdStoreStatByProdIdUserPeriodQuery, IEnumerable<ProductStoreStatistic>> Statistic;

    public HomeController(ICommandHandler<CreateCommand<Product>> CreateProduct,
                          ICommandHandler<ChangeCommand<Product>> ChangeProduct,
                          ICommandHandler<DeleteCommand<Product>> DeleteProduct,
                          ICommandHandler<ChangeProductWpriceCommand> ChangeProductWprice,
                          IQueryHandler<ProdStoreHierByUserQuery, IEnumerable<ProductStoreHierarchy>> PSTree,
                          IQueryHandler<ProdStoreStatByProdIdUserPeriodQuery, IEnumerable<ProductStoreStatistic>> Statistic)
    {
        this.CreateProduct = CreateProduct;
        this.ChangeProduct = ChangeProduct;
        this.DeleteProduct = DeleteProduct;
        this.ChangeProductWprice = ChangeProductWprice;
        this.PSTree = PSTree;
        this.Statistic = Statistic;
    }
```

Then `Verify` method throws exception similar to the first one:

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type HomeController failed. The constructor of type HomeController contains the parameter with name 'CreateProduct' and type ICommandHandler<CreateCommand<Product>> that is not registered. Please ensure ICommandHandler<CreateCommand<Product>> is registered, or change the constructor of HomeController. There is, however, a registration for IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<CreateCommand<Product>>>; Did you mean to depend on IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<CreateCommand<Product>>>?

Maybe you'd give me an advice how to solve this problem via `Repository` pattern?

Comment: @OrelEraki No, it doesn't help me, because of resolving mechanism, but not the problems with instantiating controller

Comment: Hi Dmitry, we see this same question popup again and again. That implies that the exception message isn't clear enough. After reading the answer on the duplicate question, can you propose an improved exception message that would have prevented you from asking this question? That would prevent any future users from falling into the same trap. Thanks.

Comment: @Steven I did write above that this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004648/simple-injector-fails-if-using-verify-before-setting-dependency-resolver-for-mvc) doesn't solve the problem. It throws it again.Second url throws another exception which is similar to this except last 2 sentences with another types

Comment: Dmitry, you should replace this line: `container.RegisterCollection(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typesToRegister);` with this: `container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typesToRegister);`. If it throws another exception, post a new question with the details here on SO.

Comment: Also note that your `HomeController` has three identical `ICommandHandler<ICommand<Product>>` dependencies, which you call differently. Simple Injector will have no idea which implementation to inject if you have multiple implementations of this. I would expect to see an `ICommandHandler<CreateCommand<Product>>`, `ICommandHandler<ChangeCommand<Product>>` and `ICommandHandler<DeleteCommand<Product>>` instead.

Comment: @Steven I've updated my answer with your advices

Comment: Hi Dmitry, the exception message is a bit confusing, but what you should separate the open-generic registrations from the rest. e.g. `container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), closedTypesOnly); container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(ChangeCommandHandler<>)); container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(CreateCommandHandler<>)); container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(DeleteCommandHandler<>));`.

Comment: @Steven I' ve also thought about that decision. Can you please explain how to get only closed types?

Comment: You can set `IncludeGenericTypeDefinitions = false`. But there's an easier way. You can simply call `container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());`. When supplying `Register` with a list of assemblies, it will by default filter out open-generic types, composites and decorators.

Comment: @Steven Thanks a lot! I'll try this and write about results.

Comment: @Steven I've recently checked your advice and seems like it works greatly! Thanks a lot!